# How to solve the following system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}xy + \frac{4}{xy} = 4 \\ 2x-y  \; \;= 4 \end{cases}$$

I just defined y, but still can not proceed, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Rearrange the first equation to find $(xy-2)^2=0\iff xy=2$

$$4=2x-y=2x-\dfrac2x$$

Rearrange to form a Quadratic equation in $x$

Comment: Thanks for help!